# How to install SWIG on Linux centos

Tags: swig

I want to install SWIG on My linux server to test some stuff.

How can install that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a few options. The easiest is to check for a binary package in the CentOS repository.

```
sudo yum install swig
```

Alternatively, you can download SWIG from http://www.swig.org/download.html, untar it, ./configure, make, sudo make install and you're done.

Of course, finding the proper dependencies may be a little difficult, but with a little bit of Google-fu, you'll find what you need.

Comment: SWIG is pretty independent if you're building from source. But you do need to have the devel packages for the language you want to build extensions for.

Comment: Unfortunately only installs swig 2.0, not 3.0. I hate CentOS.