# Trouble Installing M2Crypto on CentOS

Tags: python, django, centos, easy-install, m2crypto

I am deploying a Django Ecommerce site hosted on Webfaction

I have an identical problem as outlined in this post, here: http://community.webfaction.com/questions/1500/installing-m2crypto.

To summarize, whether using a downloaded tarball or `easy_install-2.7 M2Crypto`, the installation fails spitting out the error `"unable to execute swig: No such file or directory"`.

But I followed the answers in the last question, comparing the tarbal to the SVN and it appears all files are present. I am handcuffed to M2Crypto because of client constraints, so I must get this installed.

My error message is slightly different from the linked error:

```
Searching for M2Crypto
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/M2Crypto/
Best match: M2Crypto 0.21.1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/M2Crypto/M2Crypto-0.21.1.tar.gz#md5=f93d8462ff7646397a9f77a2fe602d17
Processing M2Crypto-0.21.1.tar.gz
Running M2Crypto-0.21.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-XNqvUW/M2Crypto-0.21.1/egg-dist-tmp-TmSQt9
unable to execute swig: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
```

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Try installing SWIG: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050520/how-to-install-swig-on-linux-centos

Comment: I don't have sudo access, so how do I install SWIG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't get the system admin for the computer to install it for you then download the tarball from http://www.swig.org/download.html, untar it and execute

```
./configure --prefix=/home/username/bin
```

then do the normal make and make install. After that make sure that /home/username/bin is in  your PATH environment so the system knows to look there.

Hope this helps, but in the future, installation questions like this are not for SO, try SuperUser instead for that.

Comment: I appreciate the help, and you're right this should be on superuser, I'm jsut in such a haze from being eyeball deep in this launch for the past two days that I made a mistake.  I do have one question though: the ./configure returns -bash: ./configure: Permission denied.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you execute `ls -l configure` in the swig-2.0.10 directory, isn't the permissions set to `-rwxrwxr-x`?
If not change them by using `chmod u+x`.